# Changing c# class library settings breaks reference.cs tool generated code

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, class-library

OK, somewhat of a newbie on this--I have a class library project. I added a web service call to the project, which later i decided I did not need. So, i went to the Project name in Solution Explorer, right-clicked, got the GUI for properties, went to Settings, right-clicked the row for the web-service and clicked delete. Neat and clean, right? Nope. After I deleted, I did a build and now the project will not compile. It throws the following error:

> 'Security.Properties.Settings' does not contain a definition for 'Security_webtest_Service' and no extension method 'Security_webtest_Service' accepting a first argument of type 'Security.Properties.Settings' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) C:\Security3\FOASecurity\Web References\webtest\Reference.cs    39

Refrence.cs is a tool-generated code file, and there is a warning to not muck with it. Any idea what i need to do to get the project to no longer reference this web service that was deleted?

Answer (score 1):

You just deleted the setting for the reference, not the reference.  Expand the project in Solution Explorer, then the Service References then remove the reference there.  for more information see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb628652.aspx

It's basically the same for a "Web Reference".  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d9w023sx(v=vs.80).aspx for specific details about web references if it wasn't obvious from the above.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Peter. Even if i remove the reference from the web references folder, won't the code still hiccup about no web service available?

Comment: OK, I should just keep quiet and follow instructions. Removed the web reference and build again. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Sometimes it's not clear, and sometimes it's hard to find the instructions :)  No point in keeping quite when you can get help